# how to change metro app WINJS Sqlite database path

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

i am developing windows8 application using HTML5 and Javascript. I am using SQLite3-WinRT database plugin, provided by GIT HUB https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT.

I have successfully integrated the plugin within my app and its working like charm, now the problem is I want to change the database path from

```
var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\database.sqlite';
```

to

```
var dbPath = \pages\js\ + '\\database.sqlite';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that path would be `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.path + "\\pages\\js\\database.sqlite"`

You should however be aware that you cannot write into this location, just use it as a read-only database.
Have a look at the [`ATTACH`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command if you want to read data from a provisioned database in addition to having a read-write database.